# Exponential distribution of the time between recurrences

Tags: self-study, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Patients in a hospital are treated for certain illness. The time in days that no recurrence takes place follows exponential distribution with mean of $\theta = 27$ days.

The following table gives the recurrence times for 20 patients with an average of $\bar{t} = 27$ days.

```
____________
Time in days|   (0,10]   (10,20]   (20,40]  (40,70]    >70
____________
num patients|      5        7         4        2        2
```

a) Determine an expression for the probability of the data given in the table;
b) Determine the expected frequencies for each part in the table
c) Determine the probability that a patient will go through 15 days with no recurrence;

---

I can only find a probability P(X>15) based on the value for $\theta = 27$

$$P=e^{-\frac{15}{27}}=0.57375342$$

but I am not sure what the table data means. Any hint is welcomed.

Comment: Looks like you might need to add self study tag. Notice that if you can calculate $ P(X\ge x)$ then you can also calculate $ P (x_1 \le X < x_2) = P (X < x_2) - P (X < x_1) $ which will help you calculate expected values

Comment: The notation "(0,10]" (for example) refers to the set of all times between 0 and 10, including 10 (but excluding 0).  Presumably, ">70" indicates the set of all numbers strictly greater than 70.  The numbers of patients in the second row of the table count how many patients exhibited recurrence times within the given intervals.  As a check of this interpretation, note that 5+7+4+2+2 = 20, showing all 20 patients are accounted for in the table. It is rather surprising to read that these data are supposed to be consistent with $\bar t=67$, though: the data seem to average around 32 days.

Comment: My bad, the average is 27. (not 67). I edited the initial question too.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comment of Tristan, I think the answer to the first question is
$$
\mathrm{Prob}[\mathrm{data}] = F(0,10)^5\cdot F(10,20)^7 \cdot F(20,40)^4 \cdot F(40,70)^2\cdot F(70,\infty)^2
$$
where the function
$$
F(x_1,x_2) = \mathrm{Prob}[x_1 < X \leqslant x_2] = \mathrm{Prob}[X\leqslant x_2] - \mathrm{Prob}[X<x_1] = 1-e^{-x_2/\theta} - (1-e^{-x_1/\theta}) = e^{-x_1/\theta} - e^{-x_2/\theta}
$$
denotes the probability that an exponentially distributed variable $X$ with mean $\theta$ lies between the values $x_1$ and $x_2$.